# Installing MySQL on Ubuntu Natty with Shell Script

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I'm trying to install MySQL on Ubuntu Natty from a shell script. However, I keep running into one major issue: when I try to define the password outside of the shell script.

Below is the code to my shell script (which I have saved in /etc/init.d/install_mysql:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
echo mysql-server-5.1 mysql-server/root_password password $dbpass | debconf-set-selections
echo mysql-server-5.1 mysql-server/root_password_again password $dbpass | debconf-set-selections
apt-get -y install mysql-server
```

So what I enter in the terminal is:

```
dbpass="mysqlpass"
chmod +x /etc/init.d/install_mysql
/etc/init.d/install_mysql
```

MySQL installs, but it installs without a password, so I can just do something like `mysql -uroot` to access mysql (which I don't want).

The funny thing is if I put the password in the shell script as regular text, it works ok. So if I my install script is as follows, everything works (i.e. I must specify a password to access mysql):

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
echo mysql-server-5.1 mysql-server/root_password password mysqlpass | debconf-set-selections
echo mysql-server-5.1 mysql-server/root_password_again password mysqlpass | debconf-set-selections
apt-get -y install mysql-server
```

Is there a way I can use a shell script variable to define my password in the shell script, instead of entering the password literally?!

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I've found the answer to this.

The following is what I should have entered in the terminal:

```
dbpass="mysqlpass"
export dbpass
chmod +x /etc/init.d/install_mysql
/etc/init.d/install_mysql
```

It works like a charm now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use preseeding to configure the mysql-server.

The installation progress would look like this:

Create a file `/var/cache/local/preseeding/mysql-server.seed` which contains your password.

```
mysql-server-5.0        mysql-server/root_password_again        select YOUR PASSWORD
mysql-server-5.0        mysql-server/root_password              select YOUR PASSWORD
```

Now install your mysql-server with this config file.

```
debconf-set-selections /var/cache/local/preseeding/mysql-server.seed
apt-get -y install mysql-server
```

There are even many more configuration options possible inside the seeding file.